# Flex table is not showing my more than 50 rows

Tags: html, css

Basically i cant go up with the scrollbar, this is a table that is being filled with data from a data base, if i filled too much i cant go upside with the scrollbar, some ideas?
If someone need more information im here all day i think.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="talbe-div">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    foreach($filas->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $fila){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$fila["ID"]?></td>
            <td><?=$fila["Nombre"]?></td>
            <td><?=$fila["Cantidad"]?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }

    ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

table{
    min-width: 15vw;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

td{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a typo - talbe-div. So it worked for me when I first tried it - now I see the problem which is related to your use of flex. If you make your code into a runnable snippet and check that it shows the problem it will be easier for people to help. Remove the php and insert lots of trs in HTML instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You want your table to be scrollable but to show just 50vh in height at any time.

One way of doing this would be to put everything in a container which has height 50vh and scroll that, letting the table with its flexed outer div have as much height as they need.

Here's a simple example:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-div">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
  body {
    background: black;
  }
  
  .container {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  .table-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 50px;
    rheight: 50vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  table {
    min-width: 15vw;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  th {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
  
  td {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to change the height. If this doesn't work, please provide an example output and I am sure I can help you. Scroll always has to do with height.

```
.table-div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: if i change it to 80vh i can see up to the column 29

Comment: Try 180vh.. if this doesn't work please provide an example output so I can see the problem and fix it